# Como transformar valores booleanos de Inputs para valores em string usando C# (MVC)?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estou tendo dificuldades pra conseguir transformar valores de um input Toggle em um valor em string para ser armazenado em um um BD. O objetivo é fazer um Toggle de Compra/Venda que mostra o tipo da operação que o usuario está inserindo as informações, retornando, em string, um "C" ou "V" dependendo da opção:

[image: Basicamente esse o botão]

Mas não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do Toggle!

Esse é o codigo que estou fazendo para pegar o que o botão sai e transformá-lo nas strings

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("Tipo_ope").val().toLowerCase() === 'true')
            return "C"
        else
            return "V"
    }
 );
 </script>
```

Também tentei fazer pelo Controller, porém não consigo pegar o resultado pelo parâmetro, e não deu certo também...
Eu sou iniciante ainda nesse método MVC e ainda não entendo algumas coisas, por isso pergunto se há alguém que saiba como devo resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deve tratar isso no seu frontend, o usuário pode manipular essa função. Envie no seu formulário para a controller o valor do campo:

```
$("Tipo_ope").val();
```

obs: esse seletor talvez esteja errado, lembre-se de usar o prefixo "#" para selecionar por ID:  `$("#Tipo_ope").val();`

Quando sua controller/service tiver o valor booleano desta propriedade, ao instanciar o objeto antes de gravá-lo no banco você pode fazer uma tratativa:

```
var objeto = new objeto() 
{
    tipoOperacao = tipoOpe ? "V" : "C",
};
```

obs2: Será que não seria mais visualizável utilizar o booleano no seu banco de dados e em vez de armazenar um char ou uma string, uma flag, por exemplo "IsVenda"?

Comment: não seria o ideal... o campo irá ser consultado num Index e ele teria que ser especifico. Mas obrigado! Conseguiu esclarecer algumas coisas que não estava entendendo

Comment: Entendi. Se a minha resposta ajudou você a sanar sua dúvida, por favor marque ela como aceita. Senão, comente a dúvida restante para que eu possa editá-la.